# How is an array placed on the stack when it is declared in C?

Tags: c, stack, overflow, buffer-overflow

In order to understand Buffer Overflow Vulnerabilities, i'm looking for some clarification around what the stack actually looks when you declare an array. For the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    char b[8];
    char c[8];
```

I understand that the stack will look like:

[4 bytes a, 8 bytes b, 8 bytes c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD3et.png)

but if the code instead is:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b[8];
    char c[8]
```

What does the stack look like? I'm thinking that it will be 4 bytes a, then 32 (8*4) bytes b, and then 8 bytes for c. However, i'm not entirely sure how the indexing would work at that point (is it b[0] closest to a, or b[7]?).

Any clarification would help, thanks!

Comment: This is entirely implementation-dependent.

Comment: If you want to see how it's laid out in a particular implementation, use `printf("%p %p %p\n", &a,b, c);`

Comment: Also, it doesn't have to put them in the stack in the same order that they're declared. Because of different alignment requirements, it may rearrange them to use memory more efficiently.

Comment: If you want to understand how things work behind the scenes, you need to learn how to read assembly code. To request the assembly from gcc or clang, use the `-S` option. Or you can look at the assembly with a debugger.

Comment: What you looking for is memory alignment. You can look at it at struct level first. Because you can always have the members of struct in continues memory space.
The alignment is platform and compiler dependent, and the compiler usually provide options to how you align your variable in memory.
Furthermore, C allow you to have bit-level alignment. A few struct members can share the same byte in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you may not assume that any specific sequence will be used when placing variables on the stack. The compiler may choose the sequence.  This happens often when optimizations are used.  In this case the compiler may not allocate space on the stack until the first time the variable is referenced.

Additionally, the compiler may opt not to use the stack at all, if the variable is short-lived, and may store the variable in a CPU register instead.

In terms of how much memory is needed, it will depend on the system.  Some systems may allow allocation of 8 bits at a time.  Some systems may force everything to 32 bits of width.  Some systems may add padding to make sure that larger width variables align properly.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, I am aware that the compiler may change the sequence to be different from what was declared. I probably should have clarified that in this case it was specified that the stack would be built based on the declaration as it is a basic lesson. I am attempting to change the value of the variable a by using entries into the array b[].

As there is a separate method for inputting into b[], i'm unsure of how that would work.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do this for demonstration purposes.  In that case I would turn compiler optimizations off and use a negative index value to access a from b.  If you want to find out where a and b are being allocated, you should be able to use a debugger to see the allocated memory location of each by adding a breakpoint on the first statement after the declarations.